# R replace minimum date values per group

Tags: r

I have a df with observations on different groups for a year. However, date of the first observation can differ slightly per group (generally within the first days of the year). I'm planning to show these groups in one lineplot and I want them all to start on "2021-01-01".

How can I recode my date variable as such that the first occurrence (min(Date)?) per group is set to "2021-01-01"?

Here is a small subset, with the X, Y, Z having different starting dates. Thanks!

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18637, 18644, 18651, 18658, 
18665, 18672, 18679, 18686, 18693, 18700, 18707, 18714, 18721, 
18728, 18735, 18636, 18643, 18651, 18656, 18665, 18672, 18676, 
18686, 18693, 18700, 18707, 18714, 18720, 18727, 18735, 18635, 
18643, 18649, 18658, 18662, 18670, 18677, 18684, 18692, 18700, 
18707, 18713, 18718, 18728, 18735), class = "Date"), Maand = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("jan", 
"feb", "mrt", "apr", "mei", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", 
"nov", "dec"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), UPV2 = c(339L, 
69L, 59L, 48L, 77L, 95L, 54L, 61L, 99L, 95L, 67L, 71L, 54L, 98L, 
98L, 8L, 6L, 11L, 7L, 15L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 22L, 13L, 4L, 5L, 14L, 
14L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 13L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 
14L, 4L), VAR = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), groups = structure(list(VAR = structure(1:3, .Label = c("X", 
"Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:15, 16:30, 
    31:45), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Just revised my answer to handle custom month abbreviations in `Maand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution with `dplyr` (and `lubridate`) will target every occurrence of the minimum `Date` for each group, and replace it with your common starting date of `DEFAULT_DATE`. As of my recent [**revision**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68133527/timeline#history_08e599ac-bc69-4242-a263-1750caac4605), it will also update the custom month abbreviation in `Maand`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# ...
# Code to generate your data.frame "df".
# ...

DEFAULT_DATE <- as.Date("2021-01-01")

df <- df %>%
  group_by(VAR) %>%
  mutate(# Update the custom month abbreviation for every "min(Date)" in each group.
         Maand = if_else(Date == min(Date),
                         # Pick out the corresponding level of the factor.
                         ordered(levels(Maand)[month(DEFAULT_DATE)], levels = levels(Maand)),
                         Maand),
         # Replace every "min(Date)" in each group.
         Date = if_else(Date == min(Date), DEFAULT_DATE, Date)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Keep in mind that most of the complication here arises from your custom abbreviations for month names, as factorized (with ordering) in the `Maand` column.

Fortunately, my revised solution addresses this challenge. If a new group `"A"` were added to the mix, and its earliest `Date` were `2021-03-07`, then its `Maand` would be your custom abbreviation for "March", which in this case is `"mrt"`. When applying my transformation, that date would be updated to `DEFAULT_DATE`, which in this case is `2021-01-01`. Furthermore, the `mutate()` would also ensure that the `Maand` is updated (here to `"jan"`): to the level of the factor (here the **1st** level) that corresponds to the month of the `DEFAULT_DATE` (here the **1st** month of the year).